# Mussaf before Mincha Katana

Tags: zemanim, mistakes, mincha-afternoon-prayer, machlokes, musaf

**[This is not a request for a *psak*, as I did say *Mussaf* on time today, B"H.]**

If it is now after *Mincha Gedola*, but before *Mincha Ketana*, and there is no *Minyan*, what should an individual say first, *Mussaf* or *Mincha*?

While [chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/939953/jewish/Laws-of-the-Musaf-Prayers.htm#footnoteRef8a939953) says

> If one is praying before Minchah Ketanah, but needs to pray both
>   Minchah and Musaf at once (...) one should pray Mincha first, and then
>   Musaf. If one is praying before Minchah Ketanah and one does not need
>   to pray Minchah right away, one should pray Musaf first, take a break,
>   and then pray Minchah later.

[yeshiva.co](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=5298) omits the clause about *Mincha Ketanah* and says unconditionally that

> if it is already Mincha time, then one should say Mincha before Musaf.

and [ou.org](http://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/mon_02_25_13/) seems to agree that regardless of the current hour,

> he should recite Mincha first, followed by Musaf.

So, what is it? A *machlokes*?

Comment: Am I missing something? Doesn't look like a machloket. The 1st quote says "If it is before the time to say mincha". The other two say "mincha first", and since you didn't state what time it was, I am assuming that the other two quotes mean "after the time to say Mincha" meaning "mincha ketanah". Did I assume incorrectly? Maybe you want to clarify / edit the 2nd & 3rd quotes?

Comment: see here for an explanation http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=82008&rid=554

Comment: @DanF, from my discussion with Chabad shluchim, they're makpid to disregard zemanim (the local schul is one, so I'd know that first-hand anyway).

Comment: @DanF Better?​​

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt What are trying to say? That only Chabad are including a zeman-related clause in this halacha so that they can have a chance to fulfill their hakpada to disregard zemanim?

Comment: @NBZ, no, I am merely pointing out how it seems weird that Chabad would bring zemanim when they don't start davening until around (often after) zman tefillah. While there may be Chabadnikim who are makpid to hold by zemanim, it does not seem to represent most, thus making it somewhat inapropriate for them to include information regarding zemanim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in סימן עו - דיני התפלות בשבת וביום טוב  Paskens:

> סעיף יב': הָיוּ לְפָנָיו לְהִתְפַּלֵּל שְׁתֵּי תְּפִלּוֹת, אַחַת שֶׁל מִנְחָה וְאַחַת שֶׁל מוּסָף, כְּגוֹן שֶׁאֵחַר מִלְּהִתְפַּלֵּל מוּסָף עַד שֵׁשׁ שָׁעוֹת וּמֶחֱצָה, צָרִיךְ לְהִתְפַּלֵּל תְּחִלָּה מִנְחָה וְאַחַר כָּךְ מוּסָף, מִשּׁוּם דְּמִנְחָה תְּדִירָה יוֹתֵר, וְקַיְמָא לָן תָּדִיר וְשֶׁאֵינוֹ תָדִיר, תָּדִיר קוֹדֵם. וּמִכָל מָקוֹם בְּצִבּוּר אֵין לַעֲשׂוֹת כֵּן (רפ"ו). ‏

"Once Mincha time arrives, one has to first daven Mincha - and then Mussaf - since Mincha has priority, being more frequent."

"However, one should not do so בְּצִבּוּר - in shul with a Minyan."

This is also the opinion of the Rambam in [הלכות תפילה פרק ג](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2203.htm) - to prevent confusing people.

> יא:  היו לפניו שתי תפילות, של מנחה ושל מוספין--מתפלל של מנחה, ואחר כך של מוספין.  ויש מי שהורה שאין עושין כן בציבור, כדי שלא יטעו.‏

The Aruch haShulchan (286:15) - based on a Yerushalmi - Paskens that this only applies until the time of Mincha Ketana, after which one has to first daven Mincha.

> אמנם כשהגיע זמן מנחה קטנה, הביאו הראשונים מירושלמי - דבהכרח מחוייב להתפלל תחלה של מנחה. ‏

In 286:17 he then brings the Magen Avraham that if you do not have sufficient time left in the day to daven both Mincha and Mussaf, then you daven Mussaf, as you can "catch up" Mincha after Maariv, but there is no *tashlumim* for a missed Mussaf.

> והמג''א כתב דאם הוא סמוך לערב ואין שהות להתפלל שתיהן - יתפלל של מוסף, דמנחה יש לה השלמה ע''ש. ‏

BTW: The Aruch HaShulchan has a Lomdishe piece explaning why it's at all possible to daven Mincha before Mussaf, even though one could never bring the Mussaf sacrifices after the afternoon sacrifice, which corresponds to our Mincha.

Comment: So your answer is "Yes"?

Comment: @NBZ - I'm not sure if they argue, or simply refine each other's opinion. IOW depeding on the place & time, the rules change.